# Radio button not clickable on position

Tags: html, css

I am styling some radio buttons to make it look unique. But i got problem, the problem is when i give it position, it does give me look which i want, but i am unable to click on the radio button labels to act them as radio button. Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/codearts/pen/Grbzje) and code that is making my input radio button non clickable. I am unable to choose either as my radio button is off screen. It seem like i cannot select anyone of them.

```
input[type="radio"]{
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999;
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. Only one thing you have given `male` for both label `for`...

Comment: can you more explain what doesnt work , in my computer it works fine ..

Comment: @SankarRaj I did, i cannot choose between the radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your codepen example has a typo: `label for="male"` is also used for the female case.
Once that is fixed I can click anywhere on those labels.